# User databases not added or configured for Always On AG

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, availability-groups

I need a query to get the user databases not added or configured for Always On Availability Groups in SQL Server 2014.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [sys.databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-databases-transact-sql) which has a column called group_database_id. If this column is null then the database is not participating in an availability group. To only get user databases, restrict the query to database_id > 4.

```
SELECT name From sys.databases WHERE database_id > 4 AND group_database_id IS NULL
```